# Segmentation fault when accessing output of a Tensorflow custom GPU op

Tags: c++, pointers, tensorflow, segmentation-fault

I'm designing a custom kernel. The execusion runs fine (checked via CUDA-printfs), only when I try to print the same values in TF-Space again I get the SegFault. To me it looks like the data was never transfered from GPU to CPU back and I'm not sure if this is even done or how to trigger TF to do it.

Here is how I call the values

```
Tensor* access_output = new Tensor(DT_FLOAT,TensorShape({250,250}));
PersistentTensor* per_tensor = new PersistentTensor(*proc_tensor);
OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_persistent(DT_FLOAT,access_tensor->shape(),per_tensor,&access_output));   
CallGPUKernel()(context->eigen_device<GPUDevice>(),input_tensor.flat<int64>().data(),access_output->flat<float>().data());

#It crashes if I use
auto output =access_output->tensor<float,2>();
printf("%f\n",output(0,0)); # crash

#But also if I use
float* output_ptr = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*250*250));
output_ptr = access_output->flat<float>().data();
printf("%f\n", output_ptr[0]); #crash
```

Changing `allocate_persistent` to `allocate_temp` or `allocate_output` (with adjusted settings respectively) doesn't make a difference.

Has anyone an idea how to copy back the data that was assigned in the kernel to `access_output` to be accessible in CPU space?